# Change title of navbar based on which tab is selected?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, title

I have an iOS app where there is a navigation controller as the root controller but at one part there is a tab bar to select between views in one of the nav bars. It looks similar to the iTunes app (navigation bar on top, tab bar on the bottom). I want the title of my navigation bar to change based on which tab is selected. I have two separate controller files for each tab. Here is what I have tried to use in each so far to fix this to no avail:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"title";
[self.navigationController setTitle:@"Live"];    
[self setTitle:@"Top Title"];
```

How do I change the NavBar title based on which tab is pressed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You change the title of the bar *in* the view controller that is currently being displayed.

So for example, in view controller A that you're showing in the tab controller, you might add:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self setTitle:@"A"];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"A";
}
```

Same goes for B, C, etc.

Comment: When I try this method, it sets the title of the tab the controller is connected to to "A"

Comment: Again, same issue. it sets the tab bar title to A, not the nav bar title. If you reread my question I wrote that I have tried those 3 methods.

Comment: Strange. I'm curious too. I'll revise my answer if I find anything more.

Comment: Actually, the last one worked. Have an upvote and a checkmark. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. I see now what the problem was. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Whichever title was set last sticks though. Is there any place I can put this besides viewDidLoad so that it reloads the title each time I switch the tabs?

Answer (score 3):

In your ViewControllers that are in the tabs:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.title = self.title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the individual view controllers presented by the tab bar controller have their own navigation bars, then

```
[self setTitle:@"Foo"];
```

will set both the tab bar label, as well as the navigation bar title.

If the navigation controller is at the top level (i.e. the tab bar is inside the navigation controller), then you might have to set the navigation bar title's manually (and you'll want to do this in `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`, because these child controllers are not reloaded every time you switch), e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"Foo"];
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this navigation bar title adjustment in your `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method [`didSelectViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW1).

If this doesn't do it, you might have to clarify your question, describing the hierarchy of controllers (e.g. is the tab bar controller inside navigation bar, or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the UITabBarController, set the delegate to itself, and use the delegate to set its title when the view controller is selected:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //change the title based on viewController that is selected
    self.title = @"New title";
}
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer this kind of approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just Two Lines of Code..Only thing is, you need to use **viewWillAppear** method

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"Your Title";
}
```

PS: Inspired from Above Answers...

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;

 tabController.navigationItem.title = @"ABC";
```

This is working for me

From some R&D on internet

***You have to pass the navigationItem up the chain.
The UINavigationController shows the navigationItem belonging to its topViewController which is UITabBarController.
The UITabBarController shows the navigationItem titles in its tabs. So what you need to do is make sure that the tabBarController's navigationItem is it's selectedViewController's navigationItem***

So to recap:

> UINavigationController title = topViewController.navigationItem.title
>
> UITabBarController tabTitle =
>   selectedViewController.navigationItem.title
>
> UIViewController title = navigationItem.title