# Xcode navigation bar, tab bar, table view title not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have problem that navigation bar title is not showing, and first row of table is not showing, that happend when i embeded in tab bar controller.
See images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix this, what is the problem?

Comment: try printing navigationbar.title in NSLog wether it has any value of not. I feel it may be hidden or got blended in background color.

Comment: Could you add your layout screenshot?

Comment: I added one more image, do you mean on that screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller that is on top of NavigationControllers navigation stack is TabBarController so it will display it's title not the TableViewControllers which is TabBarControllers child.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591937/change-title-of-navbar-based-on-which-tab-is-selected) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, i just switched order tabnav and navigation, now it works.. is that good solution?

Comment: Hard to tell, it is rather not a standard solution (when navigation controller is usually the root controller). Consider that many solutions for other problems with navigation stack may not apply to your architecture.