# Navigationbar Item is same with last tab?

Tags: ios, storyboard, navigationbar, tabbarcontroller

i used a separate storyboard in one of tabs in tabbarcontroller.

when i go this tab , every thing is ok but navigation bar remained  from last tab and don’t change.

Here is my code:

```
//storyboard:
     _tgaduser=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"story_main"];


_mainTabsController = [[TGMainTabsController alloc] initWithPresentation:_presentation];
        [_mainTabsController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_contactsController, _callsController, _dialogListController,_tgaduser,_accountSettingsController, nil]]; //walli
```

P.S. :
(other tab don’t used of storyboard and navigatiobbar with item change when i switch the tabs.)

this post was useful but not gonna help:

[Change title of navbar based on which tab is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591937/change-title-of-navbar-based-on-which-tab-is-selected)

Answer (score 0):

when doing this

```
[_mainTabsController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_contactsController, _callsController, _dialogListController,_tgaduser,_accountSettingsController, nil]]
```

use

```
UINavigationControllers
```

instead of the actual controllers.

And have the controllers you intend to show as the root controller for each navigation controller in the tab (this is the case when you want to actually have navigation in that **tab**)

setting the

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
```

of a view controller will reflect on the navigation title

Comment: Thank you for helping.but i used following code to hide nav bar buttons and set  title to navigation bar.however navigationbar title change not work properly. when i  switch tab its doesn't  work in one tab.                                            - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  
   UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;
    
    tabController.navigationItem.title = @"Wallpaper";
    tabController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
    tabController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;}